# How to get webhook response data

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I'm still new to webhook. What I need to do here is to do a callback whenever there's a new registration on the registration platform called Bizzabo. This platform has provided Webhook integration by having us putting the Endpoint URL and select which action that will trigger the Webhook. I've also used Request Bin and it displays the data well.

**However, how can I echo the JSON body data like how it displayed in Request Bin in my interface URL php?**

[This is how the Webhook integration looks like on Bizzabo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohHE6.png)

[Data captured from Webhook when tested using Request Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGgZt.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Your need an endpoint which receives the callback instead Request Bin, then access it in the following way using [`file_get_contents('php://input')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

For example `http://example.com/bizzabo-callback-handler.php`

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // fetch RAW input
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // decode json
    $object = json_decode($json);

    // expecting valid json
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        die(header('HTTP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type'));
    }

    /**
     * Do something with object, structure will be like:
     * $object->accountId
     * $object->details->items[0]['contactName']
     */
    // dump to file so you can see
    file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($object, true));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on this. Quick question, based on the code, we going to dump the data into callback.test.txt? and print_r($object, true) will also be printed in this interface file?

Comment: No the second param on [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) returns it instead of printing it to buffer. If it was not present the file would contain, 1 as a result of true being returned and the dump being printed to buffer. Besides its a test and you should instead be doing something with the values like storing them in the database then using for your interface. In a callback your **receiving** data so you would not generally *see* whats posted till you log it, or use such tool as Request Bin to see the structure.

Comment: Okay so let me understand this: by using file_put_contents is to basically check whether or not the object is returned right? I could print to see the account id in the interface file by storing $object->accountId to the database  and fetch the data from the database right?

Comment: I try to use the code but there's no callback.txt file created. Or should I create the txt file put the path?

Comment: Your previous comment is right, the dump file is just for debugging so you know the structure, its not required.

Comment: Dont try any of this on localhost, or behind a NATted router etc, it wont work, though you could use something like https://ngrok.com which would work quite nice as you can debug the callback within it.

Comment: Thank you! It already work! However, I don't put contents in text file. But I serialize POST data and put in it junk file.

Comment: Ok no probs, if the question has helped please upvote and accept, cheers

Comment: @LawrenceCherone hello!, i know it's been a while since you posted this, but it really helped me understand how to get the data. But now im concerned about security, how do I make sure I'm receiving de data from the correct origin?

Comment: @gepex np, with things like this I always apply a key as a get param, then set it in the API and look for and verify the `$_GET['key']` etc, some APIs have the feature to send additional headers or POST values which you can then put it there.

Answer (score 0):

If the data receiving in compressed format(gzip) use `gzdecode`  :

```
<?php

    if (!function_exists('gzdecode')){
        function gzdecode($data){
            // strip header and footer and inflate
            return gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));
        }
    }

    // get compressed (gzip) POST request into a string
    $comprReq = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // get decompressed POST request
    $decomprReq = gzdecode($comprReq);
     // decode to json
    $jsonData = json_decode($decomprReq, true);
    // do your processing on $jsonData
?>
```